# $pull/$pop on embedded array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a simple collection with the following schema

```
{
 name:"John",
 brands:[
 {
  name:"some",
  email:"asdf@some.com"
 },
 {
  name:"blah"
  email:"blah@blah.com"
 }
]
}
```

i'm using the following query to remove the embedded object inside my  brands array field:

```
var args = {
'query':{name:"John",brands.email:"asdf@some.com"}
,update:{
'$pull':{
 'brands.$.email:"asdf@some.com"
}
}
}
```

i'm using nodejs driver for mongodb and when i run the above using following:

```
collectionName.findAndModify(args,function(req,res){

})
```

I get the following error:

**MongoError: Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array**

I guess i'm doing correct but still getting this error. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$pull` is targeting `email` which isn't an array.  If you're trying to remove the matching element, you can do it like this:

```
var args = {
  query: {name: "John"},
  update: {
    '$pull': {
      brands: {email: "asdf@some.com"}
    }
  }
}
```

or if you're trying to remove the `email` field, use `$unset` instead:

```
var args = {
  query: {name: "John", "brands.email": "asdf@some.com"},
  update: {
    '$unset': {
      'brands.$.email': 1
    }
  }
}
```